# How I can have a range of number in yaml file?

Tags: python, yaml, range

I have a YAML file like below:

```
open_udp_port_allowed:
  port:
    - 68
    - 123
    - 3702
  extraUdpRange: (49152..65535)
```

I am not sure whether this syntax is correct or not but I want to have that range in a list.
Then I want to use this YAML in a python script and create a list like
`[68,123,3702,49152,49153,...,65534,65535]`

How I could have all these numbers on a list?

Edit: I have solved my problem as below:

```
open_udp_port_allowed:
  port:
    - '68'
    - '123'
    - '3702'
  extraMinRange: 49152
  extraMaxRange: 65535
```

```
open_udp_ports_allowed_range = list(range(open_udp_ports_allowed_list['extraMinRange'], open_udp_ports_allowed_list['extraMaxRange']))
open_udp_ports_allowed_range = [f"{x:02d}" for x in open_udp_ports_allowed_range]
open_udp_ports_allowed_list = open_udp_ports_allowed_list["port"]
open_udp_ports_allowed_list.extend(open_udp_ports_allowed_range)
```

Comment: I think this may not be directly possible.  You could store `extraUdpRangeMin` and `extraUdpRangeMax`, then call `range(...)` with those values in the code

Answer (score 0):

If you can slightly change the file format. If not, perform additional transformations in the code.

```
import yaml


def read_config():
    with open("еtes.yml") as yml_file:
        result = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)
    return result


def maker_ports(ports: list, extra_start_range: int, extra_end_range: int):
    ports += [x for x in range(extra_start_range, extra_end_range+1)]
    return ports


data = read_config()
ports = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['port']
extra_min_range = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['extraMinRange']
extra_max_range = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['extraMaxRange']


print(maker_ports(ports, extra_min_range, extra_max_range))
```

To avoid storing everything in memory.

```
import yaml


def read_config():
    with open("еtes.yml") as yml_file:
        result = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)
    return result


def generate_ports(ports: list, extra_start_range: int, extra_end_range: int):
    for i in ports:
        yield i
    current_port = extra_start_range
    while current_port != extra_end_range + 1:
        yield current_port
        current_port += 1

data = read_config()
ports = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['port']
extra_min_range = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['extraMinRange']
extra_max_range = data['open_udp_port_allowed']['extraMaxRange']

for port in generate_ports(ports, extra_min_range, extra_max_range):
    print(port)
```

Comment: I dont think it is good idea to convert list or range. Range is small object that is using lazy evaluation - it doesnt allocate all items.  List in other hands allocate all items durint initalization - so you will get list with 20000+ items.

Comment: @ObjectBerry You're absolutely right, it's more of a head-on decision. I will complete the answer, thank you.

Comment: I put two files in a same directory but I am receiving  this error```     with open("еtes.yml") as yml_file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'еtes.yml'
```

Comment: @MahdisGhaffarian You need to substitute your file name in open()

Comment: I am applying exactly the same as here just to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

YAML doesn't have syntactic construction to represent range. You must create own representation for it.

Best way to do it is create new object in yaml with 2 attributes : left border and right border.

```
open_udp_port_allowed:
  port:
    - 68
    - 123
    - 3702
  extraUdpRange:
    leftRange: 49152
    rightRange: 65535
```

Now in your python code , you need object that will combine range and list (we dont want use list for that masive values, because it would be wasting memory).

This is simple class that is taking 2 parameters : array of permited ports and range of permited ports (range can be omited). It also supports creating objects directly from dictionary (Pythons converts yaml to dict and you can use it to simplify code):

```
class PermitedPorts:
    def __init__(self, ports, port_range = None):
        self.ports = ports
        self.port_range = port_range

    @classmethod
    def fromDict(cls, dictionary):
        return PermitedPorts(
            dictionary["port"],
            range(
                dictionary["extraUdpRange"]["leftRange"],
                dictionary["extraUdpRange"]["rightRange"]
            )
        )

    def isPermitedPort(self, port_number):
        if port_number in self.ports:
            return True

        if self.port_range != None:
            if port_number in self.port_range:
                return True

        return False
```

You can use it like this:

```
# i will use your yaml as input
my_ports = PermitedPorts.fromDict(input_from_yaml)
my_ports.isPermitedPort(68)    # True
my_ports.isPermitedPort(1000)  # False
my_ports.isPermitedPort(50000) # True - we are using range object here
```

You can also add methods for printing (to print what ports are permited).

Comment: I put this class in another file, and now I want to use it in my main script. how I can do the import?! I have tried many ways but not recognize the class or method! could you please help on this also?